# I want to workaround "Unable to cast the type" in the resulting Select of Linq To Entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework 6

I have a type which represents Id:

```cs
public readonly record struct Id
{
    public Id(int intValue)
    {
        if (intValue <= 0)
            throw new InvalidIdException();

        IntValue = intValue;
    }


    public static explicit operator int(Id id) => id.IntValue;
    public static explicit operator Id(int id) => new(id);
    
    public int IntValue { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return IntValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Also I have an extension method:

```cs
public static class IdHelper
{
    public static Id ToId(this int id)
    {
        return (Id) id;
    }
}
```

There is a DTO type for Order:

```cs
public class Order 
{
    public Id OrderId {get;set;}
    public string OrderDesc {get;set;}
}
```

I want to execute query like this:

```cs
var order = db.Orders
    .Select(x => new Order() 
    { 
        OrderId = x.order_id.ToId(), 
        OrderDesc = x.order_desc 
    });
```

It won't work because EF6 can't translate neither `ToId()`, nor `(Id)x.order_id`, nor `new Id(x.order_id)`.
Of course I can write:

```cs
var order = db.Orders
    .Select(x => new { x.order_id, x.order_desc })
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new Order() 
    { 
        OrderId = x.order_id.ToId(), 
        OrderDesc = x.order_desc 
    });
```

But since DTO can be large sometimes, I would like to reduce the amount of unnecessary code and used memory (ideally I would like to have `List` in the result instead of `WhereSelectListIterator`)

Is it possible to write some `ExpressionVisitor` or custom `QueryProvider` to handle `ToId()` or explicit convertion to `Id` in the resulting `Select`?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need anything complicated with expressions here, instead you can lean on C# operators doing the work for you. You already have the `explicit` operator defined which means you can simply do this:

```
var order = db.Orders
    .Select(x => new Order
    {
        OrderId = (Id)x.order_id,
        OrderDesc = x.order_desc
    });
```

Or, if you change `explicit` to `implicit`, you can drop the cast entirely:

```
var order = db.Orders
    .Select(x => new Order
    {
        OrderId = x.order_id,
        OrderDesc = x.order_desc
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for overcompilcation with the extension method which I could omit in the question, but I thought this might be easier to handle extension method in ExpressionVisitor for some reason than the convertion. Unfortunately EF6 will return "System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type". This was implied in the title of my question and also mentioned in the text that EF6 can't translate (Id)x.order_id.